# Wix bootstrapper files in use

Tags: wix

I am working on custom bootstrapper application. What should be passed to e.Result to instruct msi to ignore locked files and ask to restart later ?

Is the code below correct?

```
private void OnExecuteFilesInUse(object sender, ExecuteFilesInUseEventArgs e)
    {  
        DialogResult answer = GetAnswer();
        if (answer == DialogResult.Abort)
            e.Result = Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.Result.Abort;
        else if (answer == DialogResult.Retry)
            e.Result = Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.Result.Retry;
        else
            e.Result = Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.Result.Ignore;
    }
```